# How to make firestore create nested object as sub collections on write?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Consider my below code. I want this code to create a sub-collection called items under the collection test, but right the items added an array field in test collection. Note, this is for firestore not firebase realtime db.

```
data = {
"first": "new",
"born": 1815,
"items": [
  {
    "field": 2
  }
 ]
};
db.collection("test").add(data)
```

Answer (score 13):

Your `data` object is a single object, and when you store a single object as a document using the code you gave, that object will occupy that single document.

If you want to write data to a subcollection, you'll have to write it separately, being very clear to the API that you want a subcollection underneath it:

```
db.collection("test")
    .document("doc_id")
    .collection("items")
```

or:

```
db.collection("test/doc_id/items")
```

To put it another way, if you want to write *any* two documents, you'll have to perform to two add/update/create calls at different locations.  You can't create two documents with one call.

Comment: No, I mean I want to run a single set statement which should properties of root collection (grandparent), it's sub collection parent, and it's sub collection child by passing nested JSON. In my above question, it's only two level parent and child.

Comment: Right, I understood you.  Please read the answer again.  You're trying to update two documents at the same time.  It doesn't matter that they're nested - the still count and two documents.

Comment: You could at least use [batches](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) for simultaneous updates.