# how i can make my data appear on a nested object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My .map doesn't want to appear. Which is weird, because my data appear on my doc.id like that :

{"Activity": "CrossFit", "Adress": "Plage", "City": "Nice", "Owner": true, "members": "4", "membersList": [{"id": "", "nickName": "", "statut": ""}, {"id": "4xAIad0e4uQipMtR6Tiasb5l1yl1", "nickName": "Marcel", "statut": "en attente"}, {"id": "po1", "nickName": "gypsy2", "statut": "teletubies3"}], "text": "Viens te surpasser avec nous !", "uid": "chv1UewYaIgLvixpNcdok5dZstI3"}

I wanna catch all the objects memberlist on my .map but when i tried to updated teams.memberlist and also just Teams, my console.log is empty.

Did i foreget something ?

```
function GetFriendsRequest() {
  const [TeamsArray, updateTeamArray] = React.useState([]);
  const [TeamsMembers, updateTeamsMembers] = React.useState([]);
  let fetch = async () => {
    firestore()
      .collection("Teams")
      // Filter results
      .where("uid", "==", await AsyncStorage.getItem("userID"))
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          console.log("no documents found");
        } else {
          querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
            let Teams = doc._data;

            updateTeamArray((arr) => [...arr, Teams]);
            updateTeamsMembers((arr) => [...arr, Teams.membersList]);

            console.log("cc", TeamsArray);
            console.log(doc._data);
          });
        }
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      {TeamsArray.map((element, key) => {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <View>
              <Text style={{ color: "#5DC1D3" }}>
                {element.membersList.nickName}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling  ```doc.data()``` instead of  ```doc._data```?https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#methods_1

Comment: even if i put doc.data()my array is still empty :/

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046746/how-to-make-firestore-create-nested-object-as-sub-collections-on-write) help?