# Firestore add() not accepting object inside array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Anyone worked with firestore? Adding a new document works fine but as soon as I include the sites: [{}] array and object inside, it doesn't create the document. Any help?

[image]

So to clarify, all data is there and contain something, and if i remove the sites: [] bit, the document gets added into firestore completely fine.

Comment: Already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046746/how-to-make-firestore-create-nested-object-as-sub-collections-on-write

Answer (score 0):

You should include the error you got, but here is what I would try if I were you.

**1.** Instead of passing the array directly, I would use FieldValue.arrayUnion() like so:

```
let sitesObject = { /* your object key/values */};
```

then, inside the add() function...

```
sites: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(sitesObject)
```

**2.** You have a trailing comma that might be causing the issue. It's the comma right before closing the array [{}  **,**  ]. I would try and remove that.

I would bet that #2 is what's causing your issue.